# Skipping empty tiles in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have some randomly distributed, sporadic rectangles from which I want to extract images. Think of rectangular holes in a Swiss cheese. I'm not interested in any information between these rectangles, and when exporting would like to restrict exports as good as possible to only these areas. Since they are far apart at times, the last I want would be to also export a large number of fully empty tiles in between. But exactly this is happening, and generally many very small files are created carrying no information.

I have by now tested various combinations of clip/updatemask/region/cliptocollection etc; none of it was working. I append a quick example of the problem within the context of cloud masking via averaging (relevant part starts after the median function):

```
var geometry = 
    ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(
        [[[[6.73624171642598, 51.437187561586065],
           [6.73624171642598, 51.32404630910745],
           [6.938115495722855, 51.32404630910745],
           [6.938115495722855, 51.437187561586065]]],
         [[[8.234502214472855, 51.57395370805751],
           [8.234502214472855, 51.409785059265026],
           [8.591557878535355, 51.409785059265026],
           [8.591557878535355, 51.57395370805751]]]], null, false);


function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

var img = dataset.median();
var slctd = img.select(['B2','B3','B4', 'B8']);

Export.image.toCloudStorage({
  image: slctd.clip(geometry),
  description: 'skipexample',
  bucket: 'XXXXXX',
  fileNamePrefix: 'skipexample/test',
  scale: 10,
  region: geometry,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  fileDimensions: 1024,
  skipEmptyTiles: true
});
```

What am I getting wrong here? It feels to me like skipEmptyTiles is exactly what I need, but still many tiles are generated empty.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could export each geometry separately? If you have a lot of them, there will be a lot of clicking though.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c31a91b6b12b9117fe71886e96ec2cb8